# Conditional Iteration Through Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to iterate through this excel document with multiple conditions.

1. Once you find a name, iterate through rows looking for the additional criteria until you hit a row with text in it.
2. While the rows are blank, check another column for integers only. If it's an integer, grab a value from a certain column.
3. When you hit a row with text, keep checking for that name and continue. Once done with the excel range, get a new name.

The iteration is never getting into the rangechecker, even through there are plenty of ranges while the names are matching.

```
        For i = 0 To physid.Count - 1
        Dim physamount As Int64 = 0

        range = oxlsheet.UsedRange  'Setting the range to be equal to the length of the excel file
        For rcnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count    

            varray = CType(range.Cells(rcnt, 4), Excel.Range) 'setting varray to the range of the excel workbook
            If (IsNumeric(varray.value)) Then
                temp = varray.value.ToString
            Else
                temp = varray.value
            End If

            If (rcnt > 8) Then
                If (IsNumeric(varray.Columns(4).value)) Then
                    temp2 = varray.Columns(4).value.ToString
                Else
                    temp2 = varray.Columns(4).value
                End If

                If (temp2 = physid.Item(i)) Then
                    counter = rcnt
                    Do While (String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp2) And counter < range.Rows.Count)

                        rangechecker = oxlsheet.Range("F" & counter).Select()
                        If Integer.TryParse(rangechecker, 0) Then

                            If CInt(rangechecker) > 60000 And CInt(rangechecker) < 70000 Then

                                physamount = physamount + oxlsheet.Range("H" & counter).Select()
                                Console.WriteLine(physamount)
                                Console.ReadLine()

                            End If
                        End If
                        counter = counter + 1
                    Loop
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'Write results at the end
        Console.WriteLine(physid.Item(i))
        Console.WriteLine(physname.Item(i))
        Console.WriteLine(physamount)
        Console.ReadLine()
    Next i
```

Comment: The while-loop checks if temp2 is null or empty, yet it's initialised before this... Is this ever going to be the case?

Comment: The column (temp2) will match physid.Item(i), then I want the program to iterate until the column temp2 isn't empty anymore.